# Effective mass of pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, free-body-diagram, string

Below is the original problem:

[image]

A particle of mass $3m$ is connected by a light inextensible string passing over a smooth, fixed, pulley to a smooth pulley $P$ of mass $M$. Over this pulley passes a similar string carrying masses $m$ and $2m$ at its ends. The system is released from rest. Show that the acceleration of $P$ is

$$\frac{g(3M-m)}{3M+17m}.$$

If the expression in the question were true, and if the mass of the pulley is 0, i.e. $M=0$, that, that would mean that the system is still accelrating.. how would that be possible if the total mass on each side is $3m$?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the overall mass of pulley subsystem on the right as (M+3m) means you are going to use a single acceleration rate for that subsystem.
$$F_{net}=(M+3m)a_{M+3m}\tag{1}$$
However, we know that each pulley in that subsystem can have different velocities and accelerations. This is why normally we don't treat it this way. But, (1) is still a physically correct equation. You may be able to get the correct tension of the cord between $3m$ and $(M+3m)$, but you will need the relation between $a_{M+3m}$ and $a_{3m}$, or more precisely, $\Delta y_{M+3m}$ and $\Delta y_{3m}$, because the movement of the center of the mass of the subsystem $(M+3m)$ on the right will not be the same as that of $3m$ on the left, even though they are pulled by the same tension.

### Relation between $a_{M+3m}$ and $a_{3m}$

Since the cord length for $3m$ and $M$ is fixed, we obtain
$$\Delta y_{3m}=-\Delta y_{M}\tag{2}$$
Imagine , the average displacements of $m$ and $2m$ must be the displacement of $M$, meaning
$$\Delta y_{m} + \Delta y_{2m} = \frac{1}{2}\Delta y_{M}\tag{3}$$
Therefore, the displacement of the center of mass is *defined* as
$$\begin{align*}\Delta y_{M+2m+m}&=\frac{M\Delta y_M+2m\Delta y_{2m}+m\Delta y_m}{M+3m}\tag{4}\end{align*}$$
Here you can see, even if we insert $\Delta y_{2m}$ from (3) into (4), we still need one more constraint to directly see how $\Delta y_M$ is related to $\Delta y_{M+3m}$, and thus how $a_{M}$ is related to $a_{M+3m}$.

But why are the above conditions not sufficient? It is because (3) only says the length of the cord is fixed, and (4) is just the definition of COM, which is totally independent of our current scenario. You can see that the effect of the gravity of $m$ and $2m$ is missing. In other words, (3) and (4) still hold even when the gravitational field $g$ is weakened. However, the answer of this question must depend on the exact $g$ currently effective. Therefore, we must use Newton's second law of both $m$ and $2m$ as the final constraint. Let positive $y$ direct upward.

$$\begin{align*}F_{m,net,y}&=(+T)+(-mg)=ma_{m}\tag{5}\\[5pt]F_{2m,net,y}&=(+T)+(-2mg)=2ma_{2m}\tag{6}\end{align*}$$

From (5) and (6), we obtain the relation between $a_{m}$ and $a_{2m}$,

$$g=a_m-2a_{2m}\tag{7}$$

Inserting $\Delta y_{2m}$ from (3) into (4) and taking second time derivative of (4), we obtain

$$a_{M+3m}=\frac{(M+m)a_M-ma_m}{M+3m}\tag{8}$$

To eliminate $a_m$, we take second time derivate of (3) and insert $a_{2m}$ into (3) and obtain

$$3a_m-g=a_M\tag{9}$$

Inserting $a_m$ from (9) into (8), we have

$$a_{M+3m}=\frac{(3M+2m)a_M-mg}{3M+9m}\tag{10}$$

Equation (10) shows how the center of mass of the subsystem $(M+3m)$ moves as the pulley $M$ moves. Such a relation must exist and be unique, because there is only one situation in the real world.

Finally, we take second time derivative of (2) and insert $a_M$ into $(10)$, we have

$$a_{M+3m}=-\frac{(3M+2m)a_{3m}+mg}{3M+9m}\tag{11}$$

Equation (11) says the constant length of cords and the weights of blocks $m$ and $2m$ lead to the definite relation between displacements of mass $3m$ and the subsystem $M+3m$.

### Treat the subsystem (M+3m) as a mass point

Now it is your turn. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please provide an analysis for the motion of the centre of mass of the second pulley system. I know this can be solved by finding the relative accelerations of m and 2m w.r.t ground however, is there a way to solve it by analysing the COM of the pulley system? Just out of curiosity

Comment: I hope the above analysis helps. The displacement of the center of the mass must exist, because Newton's law should be able to explain our macroscopic world. Based on this belief, you will be able to find sufficient constraints to obtain the displacement relation (11), and then you can continue to treat the entire subsystem on the right as a mass point and use Newton's second law to find the acceleration of P.

Comment: By the way, please edit your original post. As Amit said, "Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead."

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a brilliant analysis! I finally understand this now.

Answer (score 1):

If $M=0$ then the *centre of mass* of the system of pulleys and weights will not accelerate. However, the pulley P is not at the COM of the system, so it can still accelerate.